# Python program to calculate the sun angle

Tags: python, beginner

Given a string representing the hour and minute, where: 00:00 <= time <= 23:59, the program should output the number of angles the sun is above the horizon.

- When time is "06:00" the sun angles are 0º
- At "12:00" the sun is at 90º
- At "18:00" the sun goes to 180º
- After "18:00" and before "06:00" the program should output "I don't see the sun!"

[image: sun angles]

Examples:

- sun_angle("07:00") == 15
- sun_angle("01:23") == "I don't see the sun!"
- sun_angle("12:15") == 93.75

The code:

```
import datetime as dt


def check_you_dont_see_sun(time_dt, end_dt, start_dt):
    return ((time_dt > start_dt and time_dt < end_dt)
    or (time_dt > start_dt or time_dt < end_dt))


def calculate_sun_angle(time_dt, end_dt):
    difference = time_dt - end_dt
    hours_of_difference = (difference.seconds / 60) / 60
    angle_increase_each_hour = 15
    return hours_of_difference * angle_increase_each_hour


def sun_angle(time):

    start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime('18:00', '%H:%M')
    end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime('06:00', '%H:%M')
    time_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')

    if check_you_dont_see_sun(time_dt,end_dt,start_dt):
        return "I don't see the sun!"
    else:
        return calculate_sun_angle(time_dt, end_dt)
```

***What could we improve?***

Comment: The task involves calculating some kind of angle, but it certainly isn't calculating the angle of the sun above the horizon!

Answer (score 3):

One immediate thing I would improve is the naming of your variables. While in general very descriptive, it took me a while to realize that `start_dt` is actually the time of sunset and `end_dt` the time of sunrise, instead of the other way around. I would also make these variables global constants and use those as default values. This way you can do it all in one still short and readable function.

I would add some [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describing what your function(s) do and use a compound comparison instead of two comparisons to determine if the time is day or night.

The `datetime` module is often imported as `from datetime import datetime`, although your import is also OK.

The calling of the code should happen under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), where I would also put at least some very rudimentary testing code.

```
from datetime import datetime

SUNRISE = datetime.strptime('06:00', '%H:%M')
SUNSET = datetime.strptime('18:00', '%H:%M')

def sun_angle(time, sunrise=SUNRISE, sunset=SUNSET):
    """Return the angle of the sun at `time`.
    Assumes that the sun moves 180 degrees between `sunrise` and `sunset`.
    During night return 'I don\'t see the sun!'.
    """
    time = datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')
    if not sunrise <= time <= sunset:
        return "I don't see the sun!"

    angle_per_hour = 180 / (sunset - sunrise).seconds * 3600
    time_since_sunrise = (time - sunrise).seconds / 3600
    return time_since_sunrise * angle_per_hour

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_cases = [("07:00", 15),
                  ("01:23", "I don't see the sun!"),
                  ("12:15", 93.75)]
    for time, expected in test_cases:
        output = sun_angle(time)
        print(f"solar_angle({time!r}) == {output!r}")
        assert output == expected, f"Failed: expected {expected!r}!"
```

---

The calculation of the sun angle could probably still be a bit better in order to be able to be extended for different latitudes in the future.

If this is not a class exercise or programming challenge, I would also recommend to change the interface of the function a bit. Make `time` always a `datetime` object and instead of returning a string in case of invalid input raise a custom exception:

```
class NightTimeException(ValueError):
    pass

...

    if not sunrise <= time <= sunset:
        raise NightTimeException("I don't see the sun!")
```